# ArrayndexOutOfBounds when using Picasso and GridView

Tags: android

I'm learning android, and after going through the [GridView example doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), I want to see if I can modify the example to use online images. I've modified the example code to below

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        Picasso
                .with(mContext)
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .into(imageView);


        return imageView;
    }

private String[] imageUrls = {
            "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/5N20rQURev5CNDcMjHVUZhpoCNC.jpg",
            "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg",

    };
```

However, this returns a **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2** error.

I understand that in the example code, the original array is an array of Integers. Could that be the problem? If that is the case, however, I don't understand how `R.drawable.sample_` objects are type Integers.

What is the best way to fix this?

Edit:

So after playing with it a bit more, it appears that the array must contain at least 22 links in order for it to not crash. If the array only contains 21 or less, the app will show the error again. Is there a reason why this gridview is restricting me to have at least 22 objects?

This is interesting because if I use the example code as it is, I can have as many or little elements I want without any error.

Comment: Add full logcat and mark the lines Logcat tells is a problem

Comment: Logcat is stating that this line `com.testapp.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:51)` is the issue, which is pointing to the line with `Picasso.with(mContext)`.

Comment: Do you have more than two views? If so, it makes sense that youre getting an indexoutofbounds exception, since position could be 2, 3, etc

Comment: @Zach Sorry I'm still learning, so I am not quite sure what you mean by more than two views. I only have one ImageView if that's what you're asking. I've also edited the question to further explain that it appears I need at least 22 strings in my `imageUrls` array. Is there a way for gridview to not impose this restriction? Thanks!

Comment: @user3277633 can you show me your implementation for the rest of the class?

Comment: @Zach Everything is exactly the same from the example doc except for the changes I made above. Is there a specific portion that you'd like to see?

Comment: @user3277633 yeah I'm wondering if your getCount() method is screwing things up by maybe referencing a different variable. the example mThumbIds variable has 22 indices

Comment: @Zach ...and you would be right actually. It was referencing `mThumbIds` as oppose to the newly created array. If you can answer the question, I can mark yours as correct. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `getCount()` method is referencing the right variable. In this case, `imageUrls`.

Happy coding!